# Flutter: How to load Future data from firebase to GridView?

Tags: gridview, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

Hi everybody (the ones that loves Flutter),

It is very simple (but I don't know how).

I have dynamic menu options in a Firebase database.  I need to show it to final user in a GridView.

I have a Future list (let's say Future>) that returns a list from Firebase data:

```
static Future<List<Menu>> list() async {
    List<Menu> _list = new List();
    await drMenues.onValue.listen((event) {
      Menu _menu = new Menu();
      _menu.desdeData(event.snapshot);
      _list.add(_menu);
    });
    return _list;
  }
```

Now, I need to fill my GridView with these menu options.

```
final datosMenues = list();
...
new GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 3 : 4,
  childAspectRatio: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 1.0 : 1.3,
      children: datosMenues.then
...
```

I need a little help to finish it.  I know I need a "then" because is a Future list.

Please any advice?

Comment: NOTE: drMenues is a reference to a Firebase database: DatabaseReference drMenues = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(tMenues);

Comment: You can edit your question and add additional info there. Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: I understand nothing too.

Comment: I think you can find some help in [this article](https://www.fcodelabs.com/2020/06/29/Effectively-Use-Future-Builders/).

Answer (score 11):

Here is a complete example if you need a little more help.

This is how my data is organized in Firebase:

[image: this is how my data is organized in Firebase]

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("Communities")
        .onValue,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
        map.forEach((dynamic, v) => print(v["pic"]));

        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemCount: map.values.toList().length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Image.network(
                map.values.toList()[index]["pic"],
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    });

void initState() {
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase(app: widget.app);
  database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: thank u so much i was using strembuilder for firestore and recently switched to realtime databse ,...was looking for strembuilder on realtimedatabase, now i have controll over limiting and startAt endAt functions easily

Answer (score 0):

What a have been investigating and learning, what I need is a **FutureBuilder** the gets the query in "**future:**" and builds the GridView in "**builder:**".

This is how I solved "**Flutter: How to load Future data from firebase to GridView?**":

NOTES:

**drMenues** is a reference to a Firebase database:

```
DatabaseReference drMenues = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(tMenues);
```

**Menues** is just a container for static constants and static functions.

**Menu** is a class for each data in my firebase database.

**MenuItem** is a StatefulWidget which returns a Widget to show in the GridView.

```
new FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
              future: Menues.drMenues.orderByChild(Menues.ORDEN).once(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Container();
                Map content = snapshot.data.value;
                List<Menu> lista = new List<Menu>();
                content.forEach((key, value) {
                  Menu _menu = new Menu();
                  _menu.fromValue(key, value);
                  lista.add(_menu);
                });
                lista.sort((a,b) => a.orden.compareTo(b.orden));
                return new GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 1.3,
                  children: lista.map((Menu menu) {
                    return new MenuItem(menu: menu);
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
```

If anyone need a little help on this, please let me know.

Comment: Usually when listening to the database it is a stream of data rather than a future, consider using StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder

Comment: Can you please, provide an example for StreamBuilder?

Comment: Were you able to work with the streambuilder? I tried this with a stream builder but couldn't get the gridview builder to work.

Comment: How to make a "Click event" on this ? Please let me know